# Replace em lista

Tags: python

preciso de uma ajuda no código.

```
def corrigePalavra(str):
palavra = [str[-1:], str[-2:], str[-3:], str[-4:]]
result = str
palavra_modificada = False
for w in palavra:
    if result.count(w) > 1:
        result = result.replace(w * result.count(w), w, 1)
        palavra_modificada = True

return palavra_modificada, result

lista1 = ['programaramar ee legalal','python ee showow','linguagemem de programacaocao']
aux2 = []
cont_palavras_modificadas = -1
for i in lista1:
   aux1 = i.split()
   for j in aux1:
       palavra_modificada, x = corrigePalavra(j)
       aux2.append(x)
       if palavra_modificada:
           cont_palavras_modificadas += 1
   b = " ".join(aux2)
   print(cont_palavras_modificadas, b)
```

minha saida:

```
 2 programar e legal
 4 programar e legal python e show
 6 programar e legal python e show linguagem de programacao
```

Saida Correta:

```
 3 programar e lagal
 2 python e show
 2 linguagem de programacao
```

Ou seja números  de replaces na frase e frase  após correção.

Answer (score 2):

basta colocar a variável aux2 dentro do ciclo:

```
def corrigePalavra(str):
  palavra = [str[-1:], str[-2:], str[-3:], str[-4:]]
  result = str
  palavra_modificada = False
  for w in palavra:
      if result.count(w) > 1:
          result = result.replace(w * result.count(w), w, 1)
          palavra_modificada = True

  return palavra_modificada, result

lista1 = ['programaramar ee legalal','python ee showow','linguagemem de programacaocao']

cont_palavras_modificadas = -1
for i in lista1:
   aux1 = i.split()
   aux2 = []
   for j in aux1:
       palavra_modificada, x = corrigePalavra(j)
       aux2.append(x)
       if palavra_modificada:
           cont_palavras_modificadas += 1
   b = " ".join(aux2)
   print(cont_palavras_modificadas, b)
```

Comment: Obrigado darKangel, obrigado amigo

Comment: darkangel, voce teria alguma ideia de como contar o numeros de ocorrencias, não estou conseguindo a conta está dando diferente.